# Object.assign doesn't seem to work with Function.prototype

Tags: javascript, node.js, mixins

Trying to create a mixin, for a complex feature in a library.

This was working for me:

```
const proto = Object.create(Function.prototype);
```

but now I need to do some multiple inheritance such that an object inherits from both the Function prototype and the event emitter prototype, so I want to do this:

```
const EE = require('events');

const proto = Object.create(Object.assign({}, EE.prototype, Function.prototype));
```

but that was not working as expected.

So then I tried just this:

```
const proto = Object.assign({}, Function.prototype);
```

and that showed that for some reason the Function.prototype was not being copied, is my observation correct? Why would this be?

Comment: I guess Function.prototype is considered a "host object". So browsers treat it differently.

Comment: @vothaison - Why do you think Function.prototype is a host object?  It's totally part of the language, not the environment.

Comment: ftm, only talking about node.js, not browsers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per section [19.2.4.3 of the ES6 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function-instances-prototype), the properties of `Function.prototype` are not enumerable and `Object.assign()` copies only enumerable properties.   That explains why your copy ends up empty because `Object.assign()` didn't see any of the non-enumerable properties and thus didn't copy them.

So, if you want to copy the properties, you will have to get the properties with something different.  `Object.create()` is probably the best way to do it since that's what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

@jrfiend00 is probably right about this. It appears I am able to achieve what I want to do, like so:

```
const $proto = Object.create(Function.prototype);
const proto = Object.assign($proto, EE.prototype);
```

A two-step mixin.

Normally, I would expect to be able to do this:

```
const proto = Object.assign({}, EE.prototype, Function.prototype);
```

but that doesn't work, most likely for the reason jfriend00 specified. Not sure why the spec allows Object.create to work for this though.

Comment: `Object.create()` is built to handle non-enumerable properties on the prototype.  This looks like a good way to do it.

Comment: I am getting this error later on in my program => "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '_events' ", after calling proto.once(), not sure what it's about

Comment: _events is from EventEmitter. I figured it out, I am freezing the properties as read-only myself, nothing to do with the methodology above, please ignore :)